# How to use NumPy to sort a multidimensional array from highest to lowest value

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Not sure I'm finding my exact use case in the NumPy documentation, so hoping for help.

I have this array:

```
X = np.array([
            [Larry, 90%],
            [Beth, 100%],
            [Arnold, 90%],
])
```

And I'm trying to sort these horizontal pairs by the second index (i.e., the percentage) from highest to lowest value so that the result is:

```
            ([
            [Beth, 100%],
            [Arnold, 90%],
            [Larry, 90%],
])
```

I tried using argsort, but the expression below didn't work:

```
X = X[-X[:, 0].argsort()]
```

Comment: First, to refer to the second index/column, 'X[:, 1]' should be used. Second, to sort, you may want to convert a string to a float number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
X = np.array([['Larry', '90%'], ['Beth', '100%'], ['Arnold', '90%']])
X[np.array([-float(num.strip('%'))/100 for num in X[:, 1]]).argsort()]
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to this answer.